# Shift matrix columns/rows in all directions c++

Tags: c++, matrix

I have a 2d vector that looks like this:

```
a b c
d f g  // actual size is 32 x 32
h i j
```

And I want to shift the rows/columns:

```
d f g          h i j           b c a           c a b
h i j <-- up   a b c <-- down  f g d <-- left  g d f <-- right  
a b c          d f g           i j h           j h i
```

In python I can accomplish all of those in nifty one liners, such as `matrix = [row[-1:] + row[:-1] for row in matrix]` to move the columns to the right. But, c++ doesn't use the handy `:` in list indexes or negative  indexes. Well, not negative indexes like in python at least.

Anyway, I'm looking for a good way to do this. I've seen lots of other SO questions about swapping rows, or rotating, but none I have seen have solved my problem.

Here's my first take on moving columns to the right:

```
vector<vector<string>> matrix{{"a","b","c"}, {"d","e","f"}, {"g","h","i"}};

for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
{
    vector<string> col{matrix[i][2], matrix[i][0], matrix[i][1]};
    matrix[i] = col;
}
```

This works, but will be very long once I write all 32 indexes. I was hoping someone could point me to something shorter and more flexible. Thanks!

EDIT: For future viewers (taken from G. Sliepen's answer) :

```
vector<vector<string>> matrix{{"a","b","c"}, {"d","e","f"}, {"g","h","i"}}; // or can be ints

rotate(matrix.begin(), matrix.begin() + 1, matrix.end()); // move rows up
rotate(matrix.begin(), matrix.begin() + matrix.size() - 1, matrix.end()); // move rows down

for (auto &row: matrix) // move columns to the left
{
    rotate(row.begin(), row.begin() + 1, row.end());
}
for (auto &row: matrix) // move columns to the right
{
    rotate(row.begin(), row.begin() + row.size() - 1, row.end()); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`std::rotate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) that can do this for you. To rotate the contents of each row:

```
vector<vector<string>> matrix{{"a","b","c"}, {"d","e","f"}, {"g","h","i"}};

for (auto &row: matrix)
{
    std::rotate(row.begin(), row.begin() + 1, row.end());
}
```

To rotate the contents of the columns, you just rotate the outer vector:

```
std::rotate(matrix.begin(), matrix.begin() + 1, matrix.end());
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what is `auto`?

Comment: See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto. Note that this site also has an excellent reference of all the algorithms that the standard C++ library provides, which include `std::rotate()`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm

Comment: Side note: The behaviour of `auto` changed dramatically 10 years ago. If your compiler is old or you are forced to build your code to the 1998 or 2003 C++ Standards, `auto` requests automatic storage duration (ie nearly useless) and using it in the manner of more recent Standard revisions will result in weird error messages.